# Can I see the real "actual" chain of methods when using the proguard whyareyoukeeping option

Tags: java, proguard

Proguard `-whyareyoukeeping` options allows you to see a chain of call to a specific class or method. From [proguard manual](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/proguard/manual/usage#whyareyoukeeping) about whyareyoukeeping:

> Specifies to print details on why the given classes and class members are being kept in the shrinking step. This can be useful if you are wondering why some given element is present in the output. In general, there can be many different reasons. This option prints the shortest chain of methods to a specified seed or entry point, for each specified class and class member. In the current implementation, the shortest chain that is printed out may sometimes contain circular deductions -- these do not reflect the actual shrinking process.

However this often gives a circular (useless) deduction. Is there a way to see the actual path used by the shrinking process, or even all the path to the methods ?